# Looking for monospaced, calligraphy-styled font

Tags: font-recommendation

The title basically summarizes the question. Is there a font that is both monospaced and looks as if written with a calligraphy broad-pen?

The purpose would be use in a programmer's text-editor (Emacs), mostly for spicing up everyday use. So

- Monospace is a strict requirement, and must cover the full ASCII range, i.e.

  ```
   !"#$%&'()*+,-./    PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
  0123456789:;<=>?    `abcdefghijklmno
  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO    pqrstuvwxyz{|}~
  ```
- Unicode support would be nice, but is optional (editor uses fallback fonts)
- Style-wise, simple calligraphy is preferred over intricate but hard-to-read designs (as commonly used for initial caps of book-chapters), as the font would be used as a 8 to 20 px screen font. The main criterion is the angle-dependent line-thickness produced by broad-pens.
- It should be a vector-based font; I do not know if a high-resolution bitmap font would work, but a low-resolution bitmap font definitely would not.

I hope it is not offtopic here (due to the intended usecase).

Comment: Regarding the close vote: I think there are sufficiently few fonts (if any) matching these requirements, so this question would actually be sufficiently narrow for this site.

Comment: A technical note: "Unicode support" probably does not  mean what you think it means. If a font is *not* Unicode-compatible, you may not even see your basic character set. (Then again, you may. It depends on how those characters are actually mapped. It may happen to be *partially* Unicode compatible.) What you want is something like "an extended character set".

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you are looking for, the following may solve your problem:

The Unicode Block *Mathematical Alphanumerical Symbols* contains script/calligraphic variants of the upper- and lowercase letters (U+1D49C – U+1D4CF) (some of them are in other Unicode blocks due to being encoded before this block was made).

There should be some monospace fonts supporting those symbols and you might exploit them for your needs (either by moving the letters to *Basic Latin* or by using the respective Unicode symbols instead of *Basic Latin* characters). Unfortunately you will not get calligraphic variants of numbers and punctuation this way.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of such a font and you are unlikely to find one.

The most significant reason for this is that a very broad nib affects the letter shape somewhat. For example, look at the letter m in a monospaced font, compared to other letters:

```
mmmmm
nnnnn
iiiii
```

You will see that the horizontal space is at a premium and if the vertical strokes were much broader, the counters (the white space) would disappear. Try looking at it in some bold weights of monospace fonts. There's simply not enough space for much stroke contrast. In order to accommodate a wide nib you would need to widen. This would be less efficient in terms of use of space, and would also cause other problems: for example, the letter i in a monospace font with different overall proportions would have lots of white space wither side. This would be especially true in a more 'calligraphic' font where the option of using slab serifs is not on the table (the wide serifs serve in part to disguise the uneven rhythm of the vertical strokes). The fact that the m fits at all is often because its letter shape is compressed horizontally, which jars with a more 'natural' calligraphic style.

Note that this is not necessarily true of non-Latin scripts, for example in Hebrew the brush angle is closer to vertical and therefore multiple vertical lines are not an issue: [this article](http://typographica.org/on-typography/typewriter-typeface-the-legacy-of-the-writing-machine-in-type-design/) has some examples of typefaces in different languages from typewriters, including a cursive example in English.

The closest thing I can suggest is the Typewriter italic from the Computer Modern family, which has a slightly more 'freehand' feel, even though there is no stroke contrast and there is no 'linking' of the letters. Given the way Computer Modern is produced, it might be possible to tweak it to get you the desired outcome, though the overall effect on the design might not be so pleasing.